# MySQL table partition strange behavior (slow query suddenly)

Tags: mysql, index, partitioning

(I asked this question in ["stack overflow"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26707722/mysql-table-partition-strange-behavior-slow-query-suddenly) and was recommended to ask in here).

(MySQL version: 5.6.15)

I have a huge table (Table_A) with 10M rows, in entity-attribute-value model.
It has a compound unique key [Field_A + Element + DataTime].

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_A 
(
  `Field_A` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `Element` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `DataTime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `Value` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `A_ELE_TIME` (`Field_A`,`Element`,`DataTime`),
  KEY `DATATIME` (`DataTime`),
  KEY `ELEID` (`ELEID`),
  KEY `ELE_TIME` (`ELEID`,`DataTime`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Rows are inserted/updated to the table **every minutes**, hence the row size of each [DataTime] (i.e. every minute) is regular, around 3K rows.

I have a "select" query from this table, after the above "inserted/updated".
The query selects one specified elements within most recent 25 hours (around 30K rows). This query usually processes within 3 sec.

```
SELECT 
    Field_A, Element, DataTime, `Value` 
FROM 
    Table_A 
WHERE 
    Element="XX" 
    AND DataTime between [time] and [time].
```

The original housekeeping would be remove any row after 3 days, every 5 minutes.

For better housekeeping, I try to partition the table base on [DataTime], every 6 hours. (00,06,12,18 local time)

```
PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(DataTime)*100+hour(DataTime))
(PARTITION p2014103112 VALUES LESS THAN (73590212) ENGINE = InnoDB,
...
PARTITION p2014110506 VALUES LESS THAN (73590706) ENGINE = InnoDB,
PARTITION pFuture VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoDB)
```

My housekeeping script will drop the expired partition then create a new one

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_A REORGANIZE PARTITION pFuture INTO ( 
  PARTITION [new_partition_name] VALUES LESS THAN ([bound_value]), 
  PARTITION pFuture VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE 
)
```

The new process seems running smoothly.

However, the SELECT query would slow down suddenly (> 100 sec).

The query is still slow even all process stopped. It won't be fixed until "analyzing partitions" (reads and stores the key distributions for partitions).

It usually happens ones a day.

It does not happen to a non-partitioned table.

Therefore, we think it is caused by corrupted indexing in a partitioned MySQL (huge) table.

Does anyone have any idea on how to solve it?

Many Thanks!!